# What is the purpose of the "Allow" option of the client certificate mode in an Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, certificate, ssl-certificate, azure-webapps

I'm trying to secure my Azure Web Application by adding a .pfx certificate.

In Azure portal I've added my pfx file:
`App Service -> TLS/SSL settings -> Private Key Certificates (.pfx) -> Upload Certificate`

Then under the settings blade :
`Configuration -> General Settings -> Incoming client certificates -> Client certificate mode` we have 3 options : Require, Allow and Ignore.

- If I select `Ignore` I can navigate to my website wherever I have the
  certificate installed on my computer or not.
- If I select `Require` I
  can navigate to my website only If I've the certificate installed on
  my computer.
- If I select `Allow` this act like the `Ignore` option: I
  can navigate to my website wherever I have the certificate installed
  on my computer or not.

So what is the purpose of the `Allow` option?
I didn't find any litterature about it.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **"allow"** option enables authentication to your app using both certificate and AAD token.

When choosing "allow" the app will request a certificate - by that enabling an authentication with it.
But the app will also pass the request when no certificate was provided - by that enabling an authentication with a token.

Note that its the code responsibility to verify this token is valid with AAD (as it is to verify the certificate).

The other options:

- **"require"** will block the request on the AppService level where no certificate was provided, so it doesn't enable using tokens.
- **"ignore"** will not require a certificate at all, so it doesn't enable using certificates.

So "allow" solves this issue and allow the app to enable authentication with both.

Read more here: [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization#authorization-behavior)

Comment: Thanks for the link of the documentation (which was created after my question and answer it).

Answer (score 0):

`Allow` option means that the app will request a cert, but will not fail the request if no cert is presented. This is different from the `Ignore` in that the ignore options will not request for a cert in the first place.